# Community replaced http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc with https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc - why?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, robots

I just had a bunch of edits by Community popping up in my inbox which

> replaced `http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc` with https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc

What is the reason for that? Are the former ones going to be discontinued or anything like that?

Comment: See [Links to HTML versions of RFC's need to move from "tools" to "datatracker"](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/367881/289905).

Comment: The Community user literally just edited this post. I've rolled back and added code formatting in an attempt to prevent it from doing it again.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ah, ok. IMO a bot implementing such changes should not state the obvious in the edit comment but instead link to the article that explains the action. For example: replaced rfc URLs, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367881/460854

Comment: The irony that the community user has also edited the question on [se] so it literally makes no sense now.

Comment: In case of suggested edits from ***unregistered users*** (is that still a thing? Site-specific?), it would appear to be done by *Community* user. From [its user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile): *"...Own suggested edits from anonymous users"*

Comment: @Larnu It has been fixed by another user - for now :).

Comment: Based on the link @SebastianSimon gave, this was because IETF responded that the link location had moved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry for the difficulties - we received notice that the archives of the IETF's RFCs were moving; Slate and Yaakov were setting the URLs correctly.  Unfortunately it looks like there were some edge cases that maybe didn't get factored in.  Apologies for the misfires.  I've asked that Slate and/or Yaakov stick their heads in over here and see what work needs to be done to correct things.

Comment: OK. As mentioned in a comment to the question above, if the edit comment had included a link to the respective meta article, everything would have been great.

Comment: Is that edit comment chosen by the bot? Or is it set by the user starting the bot action? In the former case I'd create a feature request for the bot to ask for an explanatory link when started.

Comment: I honestly don't know.  Slate or Yaakov will know though. :-)

Comment: The comment is put in through our dev route for url-rewriting. Auto-generated based on the exact url being substituted.

Comment: I would propose using more helpful comments, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370742/460854